# Performance difference of separate DataWeave update function calls vs. nested update function calls

Tags: performance, dataweave

What is the performance difference between these two DataWeave expressions?

In this example there are three update operators. The destination branch case statement interferes with the child .*flight.destination.longitude and .*flight.destination.latitude case statements.

First is three separate update operators chained together using infix notation:

```
reservationsXml 
update {
    case flight at .reservations.*reservation.*flight -> flight - "flightCode"  
}
update {
    . . . 
    //case dest at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.*destination -> dest
}
update {
    case long at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.destination.longitude -> 
        long as Number as String {format: "###.000"} 
    case lat at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.*destination.latitude ->        
        lat as Number as String {format: "###.000"} 
}
update {
    case dest at .reservations.*reservation.*flight.*destination -> dest - "ICAO"
}
```

vs. putting the second and third update operators inside the previous case statement.

```
update {
    case flight at .reservations.*reservation.*flight -> ( flight - "flightCode" )  
    update {
        case dest at .*destination -> 
            (dest - "ICAO")
            update {
                case long at .longitude -> 
                    long as Number as String {format: "###.000"} 
                case lat at .latitude -> 
                    lat as Number as String {format: "###.000"} 
            }
    }
}
```